# I need a forward function code which forward the original message (pyrogram)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, pyrogram

```py
@bot.on_message(filters.chat(INPUT_CHANNELS) & filters.text)
def forward_message(client, message: Message):
    text = message.text
    client.send_message(chat_id=DESTINATION_CHANNEL, text=text)
```

I got this code here, but it just forwards text from the message although there is an image. I need it to forward the original message, keeping all the content such as images, videos, text, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're grabbing the `text` of a message and then use `send_message` to send a new message. If you want to actually *forward* a message, you'll have to either use [`client.forward_messages`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/forward_messages), or the bound method [`Message.forward()`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/bound-methods/Message.forward). This will actually forward a message including any media (images, videos, etc).

```py
@app.on_message(filters.chat(CHANNELS))
def forward_messages(app, message):

    # Either via forward_messages
    app.forward_messages(
        chat_id=TARGET,
        from_chat_id=message.chat.id,
        message_ids=message.id,
    )

    # or via bound method:
    message.forward(TARGET)
```

Comment: hi brother, is bound method optimal ? Im not very familiar with python, sorry for stupid questions.

Comment: @NghiaLe Bound method just means that it is a method *bound* to the `Message` type. Since you receive a Message object, you can use the bound method `.forward()` as a convenience. Check the documentation I linked in my answer.